# Angular JS - Filter based on number it contains

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js.
I have array like:

```
$scope.experience_list = ['6-7','0-1','4-5','2-3','8-10','10+', 'na'];
```

I am getting this array from ajax call. So value of array will come in any order.

I am using ng-repeat to display this array

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
<ul ng-init="experience_list = ['6-7','0-1','4-5','2-3','8-10','10+', 'na']">
    <li ng-repeat="experience in experience_list | orderBy:'toString()' track by $index">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span ng-if="experience == 'na'">Unknown</span> <span ng-if="experience != 'na'">{{experience}} years</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It is giving me result as

```
0-1 years
10+ years
2-3 years
4-5 years
6-7 years
8-10 years
Unknown
```

But I want as:

```
0-1 years    
2-3 years
4-5 years
6-7 years
8-10 years
10+ years
Unknown
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS :

```
<li ng-repeat="experience in experience_list | orderBy:$index track by $index">
```

Comment: I am also performing some operation like removing adding element

Comment: Can You give more info about your problem ? Like where are you face difficulty in adding / removing elements ?

Comment: Ok. You should consider implementing custom filter which will split the item delimited by '-' . Slice first part of it and then use that value for ordering. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**if you want to perform any function just call the function by passing $index in it. And using $index extract the value from the array in the function.**

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
<ul ng-init="experience_list = ['0-1','2-3','4-5','6-7','8-10','10+', 'na']">
    <li ng-repeat="experience in experience_list">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span ng-if="experience == 'na'">Unknown</span> <span ng-if="experience != 'na'">{{experience}} years</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just do this

```
ng-repeat="experience in experience_list track by $index"
```

You're getting right output

Here's one more approach

```
var a = ['0-1','2-3','4-5','6-7','8-10','10+', 'na']
$scope.experience_list = a.map(function(obj){
    return{
        order : obj.split('-')[0] || obj,
        real : obj
    };
});
```

> ```
> html
> ```

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="experience in experience_list | orderBy:-'order'">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span ng-if="experience == 'na'">Unknown</span> <span ng-if="experience != 'na'">{{experience.real}} years</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Just try to use the same format when to delete and push new values

Comment: ya.. but I am performing some operation also like removing adding element

Comment: I don't see any problem with that also. In that case give that exact code for which you're trouble

Comment: Ok. You should consider implementing custom filter which will split the item delimited by '-' . Slice first part of it and then use that value for ordering. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It helped me. No need to create custom filter for it.

for more info [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare)

Just sort it,

```
$scope.experience_list = ['6-7','0-1','4-5','2-3','8-10','10+', 'na'];
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
$scope.experience_list.sort(collator.compare);
```